# window.location.href opens another window

Tags: javascript

For some reason when I set window.location.href =  it opens another window.

window.location.href = 'https://MyDomain.com/Checkout/Purchase.asp';

It doesn't happen in my development environment, only production. The only only thing different that I can think of is that we are switching from http to https. If this were a straight link () it would work.

Any ideas how to get this to work correctly? The url is built with Javascript (it requires some information from the user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about specifying the target?

```
window.open("http://asdf.com", "_self");
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers can be configured to behave many ways, you have no control from javascript if it opens a new window or not.
BTW location.href is faster

Comment: The browser behavior that you're describing is accurate, but usually applies to whether a window opens in a new window or in a new tab.  If he's using the same browser to access both his dev and production environments, then this is likely not the cause. Also, `location.href` is faster to type and that's about it. The scope chain resolution savings from removing window is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried window.location.replace() instead?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this replaces the current page with the new one, including in history. Not exactly what I want.