# window.href open new window?

Tags: javascript, html

when ever i use

```
window.location.href=//some url
```

it always open a new window, this only happens when the parent window is an dialog box. Any idea what i did wrong?

i tried using

```
window.open("http://asdf.com", "_self");
```

as suggested on this thread [window.location.href opens another window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678155/window-location-href-opens-another-window) but it is still not working

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent window

```
window.open("http://asdf.com", "window_name","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=no,width=650,height=650");
```

code in a parent window to open new

```
window.open('http://www.google.com', 'window_name', '_self')
```

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled upon this question and thought I would offer an alternative.  If you run into trouble with popup blockers, you can use plain old HTML to launch a url in a new window/tab.  You won't have as much control over that is displayed (scrollbars, toolbar, etc), but it works even if javascript is disabled and is 508 compliant:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Open new window</a>
```

You can read more about the various target attributes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/a